# Системы координат в Windows XP и в Windows 7 разные

Tags: winapi

При определении координат пиксела в конкретном окне в результате выясняется что они разные в Windows XP и в Windows 7 из-за разных оформлений окон, Как можно решить это? 
Или как определить ширину ободка оформления окна?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используя функции `GetClientRect` и `GetWindowRect`, можно получить клиентскую и общую область окна. Разница между ними - это и есть неклиентская область.

Плюс GetSystemMetrics с параметрами `SM_CYCAPTION` и `SM_CYBORDER` дают размер заголовка и обводки.